# How to check a checkbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to use jquery to check my checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="restricted_access">Restricted Access?</label>
</div>
```

My js:

```
$('#restricted_access').prop('checked', true);
```

But this just returns

`[<input type=​"checkbox" value id=​"restricted_access" checked=​"checked">​]`

Can someone help?

Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ysh1wt5y/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the checkbox checked? Try `.prop('checked', true);`

Comment: What is your problem with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#restricted_access').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Hi - I tried, but it's not working. Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ysh1wt5y/

Comment: you are not using Jquery library

Comment: try this:
document.getElementById('restricted_access').checked = true;

Answer (score 0):

The pure JavaScript way:

```js
document.getElementById('restricted_access').checked = true;
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="restricted_access">Restricted Access?</label>
</div>
```